# JQuery Autocomplete within MVC doesnt completely function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, jquery-autocomplete

I have a auto complete box set up. 
however when a user types in the box a list of every single item appears.
Not relating to anything the user is typing in.

What am i doing wrong?

Jquery:

```
 var availableTags = '@Url.Action("PopSearch", "Home")';
    $("#searchtxt").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
```

Controller function:

```
public ActionResult PopSearch()
    {
        IndustryManager manager = new IndustryManager();
        ProductRangeManager manager2 = new ProductRangeManager();
        ProductCategoryManager manager3 = new ProductCategoryManager();

        IList<Industry> industryList = manager.GetIndustries();
        IList<ProductRange> rangeList = manager2.GetAllProductRanges();
        IList<ProductCategory> categoryList = manager3.GetAllProductCategories();

        var attributes = industryList.Select(x => x.Name)
            .Union(rangeList.Select(x => x.Name))
             .Union(categoryList.Select(x => x.Name)).ToArray();

        return Json(attributes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the server request. Probably you have a request to the server something like

http://yoursite.com/Home/PopSearch?term=Something

Where something is what user inputs in the textbox. It means that you need to filter it on the server side and return already filtered data.

```
public ActionResult PopSearch(string term)
{
    IndustryManager manager = new IndustryManager();
    ProductRangeManager manager2 = new ProductRangeManager();
    ProductCategoryManager manager3 = new ProductCategoryManager();

    IList<Industry> industryList = manager.GetIndustries();
    IList<ProductRange> rangeList = manager2.GetAllProductRanges();
    IList<ProductCategory> categoryList = manager3.GetAllProductCategories();

    var attributes = industryList.Select(x => x.Name)
        .Union(rangeList.Select(x => x.Name))
         .Union(categoryList.Select(x => x.Name)).ToArray();

    var result = attributes.Where(x => x.ToLower().StartWith(term.ToLower()));

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Sure it doesn't. I just built link whitch you should expect on every ajax call from autocomplete to your server.

Comment: Actually you don't need to change anything in your javascript. you need to modify your action.